# How do I store an object which contains an object to Firestore in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm connecting to Cloud Firestore from my Android app. I need to save an object; That object contains a number of strings and ints, and also a couple of objects.

So, I have the following (simplified):

A `MyColourList` object which contains:

```
String name, description;
String[] colours;
```

A `MyGrid` object contains the following:

```
String name, description;
int numberOfLinks;
MyColourList colourList, colourListDefault;
```

I want to save a new `MyGrid` object to Firestore. The Firestore data structure is as follows:

```
grids > grid1ID > colourList
                     > name
                     > description
                     > colours
                          > 1
                            > White
                          > 2
                            > Black
                 > colourListDefault
                     > name
                     > description
                     > colours
                          > 1
                            > White
                          > 2
                            > Black
                 > description
                 > name
                 > numberOfLinks
```

To save this without the `colourLists` I just do this:

```
Map<String, Object> newGrid = new HashMap<>();
        newGrid.put("name", nameString);
        newGrid.put("description", descriptionString);
        newGrid.put("numberOfLink", num_links);
        databaseRef.collection("grids").add(newGrid);
```

which works fine.

However, when I try to add in the `colourLists` by doing this:

```
Map<String, Object> newGrid = new HashMap<>();
        newGrid.put("name", nameString);
        newGrid.put("description", descriptionString);
        newGrid.put("numberOfLink", num_links);
        newGrid.put("colourList", colourList);
        newGrid.put("colourListDefault", colourListDefault);
        databaseRef.collection("grids").add(newGrid);
```

I'm getting the following error and a crash: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type: myapp.ColourList(found in field colourList)`

I assume I need to map the colourLists in some way before I do this, but I can't find any examples of that. Can anyone advise me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Cloud Firestore, you should use either POJO classes or either maps of primitive types but not mix them together. In your particular case, since you already have a `MyGrid` object, you should just write it directly to the database and then update it later, using the following lines of code:

```
MyGrid myGrid = // create your MyGrid object
yourReference.set(myGrid);
//Create your MyColourList objects and set the properties
MyColourList myColourList = new MyColourList();
MyColourList colourListDefault = new MyColourList();
myGrid.setColourList(colourList);
myGrid.setColourListDefault(colourListDefault);
yourReference.set(myGrid, SetOptions.merge());
```

It's true that this operation will have the cost of two write operations (one for adding the `MyGrid` object and second to update it) but this is the only way in which you can achieve this. The difficulty in allowing maps of POJOs is that it isn't clear how they should be extracted. So unfortunately, the Firestore SDK doesn't support this feature. It's only supported when you're updating the entire document using [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#set(java.lang.Object)) method. Please also see the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects) for an example.

Comment: Hi Shanon! Is there everything alright, have you tried my solution above?

Comment: Thank you! I haven't been online for a couple of days, but will try this now. It makes sense.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: Quick question: is myGrid.set() a preexisting function, or do I need to write that? Because it's coming up red. If I need to write it, I assume it's just setting the colourList variable in the myGrid object?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Should be `setColourList()` and `setColourListDefault()`, the corresponding setters for your `colourList` and `colourListDefault` fields. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: That seems to work - I've been able to set the colourLists before saving the myGrid to the database, though, and write it all in one go... I think you said I shouldn't be able to do that... Am I doing something wrong which will come back to bite me later?!

Comment: No, that's correct. If you think that my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681906/can-i-retrieve-two-documents-from-the-database-in-two-different-functions-simul)** also helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a model or Pojo which contains all your variables, arrays and other objects. Then just put that to firestore database by using this:-

```
firestore.collection("grids").document(grid1ID).add(your_object).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {

    }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity_Name.this, "Error In Saving Details: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     });
```